# android AutoCompleteTextView slow

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView with 300k+ entries, it works fine with faster phones, when i try using it on slower phones it take 3-4 second to show suggestions. Anyone have any suggestions.
Help me. Thanks in advance.

Sorry if I am not being clear.
300k+ entries load from app resource.
I meant Faster phone like Galaxy Note 5, Note 3 and Nexus 6.
Slower phone like HTC desire  626.
here is the code

```
  final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview4);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, somearray);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textView.setThreshold(1);
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what do you mean by faster and slower phones ?

Comment: You would need to add more details and put some code for anyone to provide assistance. For instance, are the entries in an sqlite database on your device or accessed over the network? When you say "slow" and "fast" phones what exactly do you mean? Show your code so we can help you find any possible bottlenecks.

Comment: `Sorry if I am not being clear. 300k+ entries load from app resource.` store your data in `sqlite` database to get the data faster than now

Comment: I put data as XML  Strings , compiler would pre-compile the data and not during running . so it doesn't actually load from asset folder. I thought sqlite would be slow since it has to compile the data while running.

Comment: no, it does not have to "compile" the data

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong, are you suggesting the way i assign the data is slower than sq-lite.

Comment: of course, i assume you are using `ArrayAdapter` / `BaseAdapter` that stores all of your data?

Comment: I use array to store data, then i assign it to ArrayAdapter<String>.

Comment: use `SimpleCursorAdapter` then and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: okay i will try that method. I will later update whether it is improved. Thanks.

Comment: @Yazan no i am not looping. I am using default AutoCompleteTextView for the suggestion. I just supply the array. see my code. thanks

Comment: android.widget.Filter  can help you,performFiltering()..publishResults()..;http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/Filter.html

Comment: @sanemars Thanks I will look into that.